# How do you add/remove a list of classes from an element?

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive

Most question and answers I've seen related to this say to use ng-class. However, I have a list of many classes of which I need to add 2 of to each element. This is in a directive.

```
"<div><div class='card {{suit}} {{value}}'></div></div>"
```

I don't think listing out every class with ng-class with a boolean is viable here. Is there an angular way of removing and adding classes?

Something like:

```
link: (scope,elem,attrs){
    elem.firstChild().removeAllClasses();
    elem.firstChild().addClass(attr.suit, attr.value, "card");
}
```

Comment: May be you can write a function which returns a class or set of classes based on some logic. <div ng-class="getClasses()"></div>

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If the code is in your directive, you can just use jqLite.

```
link: (scope,elem,attrs){
    elem.removeAttr('class');
    elem.addClass(attr.suit);
    elem.addClass(attr.value);
    elem.addClass("card");
}
```

here is a list of all the supported jqlite functions

https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/function/angular.element

Comment: Ahh, didn't realize that removeAttr could be used for class. Was going to go the jQuery route with its removeClass() function. Thanks!